# Renaming a subdomain on current wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain, permalinks

I've created a new replacement website for the company that I work for on a subdomain of that company's current site. Almost ready to launch but I created the site on theme.example.com and I want to rename the subdomain to companyinitials.example.com. Can I just rename the subdomain folder in the site's cpanel and expect that to work, with maybe some permalink edits? Or is there a better way to proceed?

-All my thanks.

Comment: Renaming the folder will not be enough. You have to appropriately change the subdomain name (via cPanel if you can, not familiar there) so the webserver's virtualhost and other relevant configurations are updated accordingly. Following that, you need to modify define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE') in wp-config.php, and then update various tables in the database that have saved the old domain name. This includes updating of all permalinks on posts.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I can definitely edit the subdomain through its cpanel link and edit the the wp-config, no problems  there. Then I'll just search the db for instances of the old domain and edit those. Much appreciated

Comment: I went through this and it was a pain. Here is what I noted down back then. Update (tablename.columnname): wp_blogs.domain, wp_site.domain, wp_sitemeta.siteurl, wp_options.siteurl, wp_options.home. Then, to update permalinks in existing posts, run `UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid, 'http://{old_domain}/', 'http://{new_domain}/')`.

Comment: Thanks marekful that will come in handy vs. a search, luckily there is only one blog post thus far, but I know that photos are also stored in the database so hopefully that will not be too big of a hassle.

Comment: I'm not seeing a DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE key within wp-config, wondering if its possible that in updated versions of wordpress that this was removed from the wp-config file?

Comment: This was a multi-site WP installation so DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE may be related to that. Anyways check in wp-config if the old domain appears anywhere.